# Insert from ajax working, need to make changes to check for existing conditions to update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to fix an issue. The user can currently create content within a form that upon submission makes an ajax call. WHen the call is made it creates a mysql record for the actual content, gets the ID of that content record, and then creates a record for the 'panel' that houses that content (relating the page ID, panel type, and content all toegether).

This works perfectly, but if they try to edit the content in the form and submit that it just creates another record.

The JS/AJAX below is passing the panel_type, pageID and content as hidden fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#leftHalfForm").submit(function(e){

      var string = $('#leftHalfForm').serialize() + '&page_id=' + page_id;
      console.log(string);

    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addPanel.php",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){

            }
        });

    return false;

});

</script>
```

So when the 'form' is submitted, the ajax calls this below PHP script which inserts the content, gets the ID of that content insert, and then creates a panel record containing the panel type, the page ID, and the content ID:

```
$content = $_POST['page_content'];

$addContent = "
    INSERT INTO content(content)
    VALUES('$content');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addContent) === TRUE) {
    $cont_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
    $data['last_insert_id'] = $cont_id;
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addContent . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}

$panelID = $_POST['panel_type'];
$pageID = $_POST['page_id'];
$addPanel = "
    INSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
    VALUES ('$panelID', '$pageID', '$cont_id');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addPanel) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addPanel . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

This works perfectly on a new page with an empty panel. But if they submit this form (creating a panel record and a content record) then click back into it to edit something, then on that AJAX call I'd like to be able to check and essentially say "If a record exists for this panel type on this page, update the content record associated with it."

Example:

If the user clicks into the form and creates content text "This is some text content". Say the pageID of this current page is 123 and the panel type is 2. This record is created:

Content table

```
ID |  Content
------------------------------
52 | This is some text content.
```

Panel table

```
panel_type_id  |  page_id  |  cont_id
-------------------------------------
2                 123           52
```

Now if they edit this and hit submit, I'm already passing the panel_type_id and page_id so all I want to do is see that panel_type_id of 2 and page_id of 123 already exist, so I just need to update the content record associated with it (content ID of 52).

It seems like it should be simple enough but I'm not sure how to keep the current functionality for new panels while accommodating the editing/updating of what's already there.

Comment: You can add a simple condition - if page id exist in the panel table - data in the content table will be updated without any changes in the panel table, if doesn't exist - will working current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick would be to do an additional query to check if there are records that match that panel_type_id and page_id. So we do a count, if the count returns 0 then we insert a new record, else we update the existing records.

```
$checkIfExists = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM panels WHERE panel_type_id = $panelID AND page_id = $pageID";
if($mysqlConn->query($checkIfExists)->count = 0){
$q= "
    INSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
    VALUES ('$panelID', '$pageID', '$cont_id');
";
} else {
$q= "
    UPDATE panels SET cont_id = $cont_id WHERE panel_type_id = $panelID AND page_id = $pageID
";
}

if ($mysqlConn->query($q) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addPanel . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

Comment: Ok I think this mostly makes sense except, if the record DOES exist, then I want to only update the content of my content table. So the initial submit creates a panel record and content record. I just want to check if the pageid/panel type exists and if it does, just update the 'content' column in the content table with that ID